# Find inside the .parent()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to hide some fields. How can I add .parent() after ".ms-alternatingstrong"

The code:

```
 $("#WebPartWPQ2").find(".ms-alternatingstrong:not(:Contains("+user+"))").hide();
```

I tryied with: , but not working

```
 $("#WebPartWPQ2").find(".ms-alternatingstrong.Parent:not(:Contains("+user+"))").hide();
```

Comment: can you show us the html and tell us the exact need. Then there may be an easy solution for this problem

Comment: In your code you wrote .Parent instead of .parent(), and I suggest using .not() for readability

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$("#WebPartWPQ2").find(".ms-alternatingstrong").parent().not(":contains("+user+")").hide();
```